# Определение уникальности из двух чисел

Tags: php, mysql, логика, хеширование

Пример, есть два столбца **tid** и **fid**: 
2, 3

1, 3

3, 2

124, 23

12, 423

Числа в каждом столбце могут повторяться.
Одновременно в двух столбцах числа не должны повторяться.
При работе с таблицей, было бы удобно иметь третье числовое поле id с уникальным значением на основе двух полей **tid** и **fid**.

Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: А от нас что требуется?

Comment: а что известно про значения столбцов?

Comment: Что еще нужно знать?

Comment: Значения любые числовые

Comment: ВОРОН, исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> не должны повторяться

можно, например, [создать индекс](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) с уникальными значениями:

```
create unique index on таблица (tid, fid);
```

тогда любые изменения (в том числе при вставке строк) в столбцах `tid` или `fid`, нарушающие уникальность, будут отвергнуты системой управления базами данных.

> третье поле `id`

можно, например, [создать `view`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), в котором будет вычислимый столбец:

```
create view название as select concat_ws('_', tid, fid) as id, * from таблица;
```

в данном примере значениями столбца будут `2_3`, `1_3` и т.д.

пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aa518/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (tid int, fid int);

create unique index raz on t (tid, fid);

insert into t values
   (2, 3)
  ,(1, 3)
  ,(3, 2)
  ,(124, 23)
  ,(12, 423)
;

create view vid1 as select concat_ws('_', tid, fid) as id, t.* from t;

create view vid2 as select (tid * 1000 + fid) as id, t.* from t;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aa518/1/0)**:

```
| tid | fid |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |   3 |
|   2 |   3 |
|   3 |   2 |
|  12 | 423 |
| 124 |  23 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from vid1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aa518/1/1)**:

```
|     id | tid | fid |
|--------|-----|-----|
|    1_3 |   1 |   3 |
|    2_3 |   2 |   3 |
|    3_2 |   3 |   2 |
| 12_423 |  12 | 423 |
| 124_23 | 124 |  23 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from vid2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aa518/1/2)**:

```
|     id | tid | fid |
|--------|-----|-----|
|   1003 |   1 |   3 |
|   2003 |   2 |   3 |
|   3002 |   3 |   2 |
|  12423 |  12 | 423 |
| 124023 | 124 |  23 |
```

Comment: Уникальные индексы для каждого столбца по отдельность ставить нельзя, значения в одном столбце повторяются, одновременно в двух столбцах - нет. Нужно своего рода уникальный индекс для двух значений из двух столбцов. Третье поле id хотелось бы числовое

Comment: @Ivan_Aka, предложенный «сборный» индекс именно так и работает.

Comment: Третье поле id хотелось бы числовое

Comment: @Ivan_Aka зачем вам третье поле, если уникальность будет поддерживаться без него?

Comment: Сборный индекс...

Comment: @Ivan_Aka, ну, можете `id` представлять как, например, `tid*1000+fid`. сейчас sqlfiddle заработает, и я вставлю пример в ответ.

Comment: если tid всегда меньше тысячи :) потому я и спрашивал, что известно про них :)

Comment: Вообще-то сборный индекс мне пожалуй подходит)

Comment: @alexander barakin, Спасибо, я увлекся и упустил из виду функциональность индексов mysql. В моем случае это то, что нужно было.

Comment: @Ivan_Aka, sqlfiddle заработал, я добавил примеры в ответ.

Comment: @alexander barakin, Да, это тоже решение. На мой взгляд проблема в Query 3: это огромные числа при больших tid и fid. А Query 2: решение, но, правда, не числовое.

Comment: @Ivan_Aka, придумайте функцию, которая будет делать более компактное хэширование, и используйте.